# Use many to many relationship or multiple columns?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a product, which can belong to one (or more) of 5 possible categories.

**The number/name/structure of categories will not change**

Should I be using a many to many relationship and insert 5 records in the category table, add a join table and add foreign keys etc? Or just add 5 fields to the product table? I feel the latter seems more efficient, but goes against the principles of normalization.

i.e.

```
Product:
   - id
   - name
   - is_cat_a : bool
   - is_cat_b : bool
   - is_cat_c : bool
   - is_cat_d : bool
   - is_cat_e : bool
```

**OR**

```
Product
   - id
   - name
Category
   - id
   - name
ProductCategories
   - product_id
   - category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested:

A product, which can belong to one (or more) of 5 possible categories only.

Then, in my opinion, create two tables:

```
**1. Category**
Id int,
Name varchar,
IsActive bool and other regular columns

**2. Product**

   - id int,
   - name varchar,
   - cat_a : int,
   - cat_b : int,
   - cat_c : int,
   - cat_d : int,
   - cat_e : int
```

Keep all category column's default as zero.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as there are only 5 rows in the category table, so the reference to this table is negated by having 5 columns